# Creating a Distribution

Tags: distributions

Say I want to create a multivariate distribution that perhaps, as an example, looks something like this.

```
f(x1,x2,x3)=f1(x1)*f2(x2)*f3(x3)*InverseStandardNormal[F1(x1)]*...
```

Obviously the function I am working on doesn't quite look like this but I hope you get the picture. It is a multivariate joint distribution that relies on individual marginal distributions, cumulative distributions, as well as other scaling factors.

I am not sure how to achieve this despite spending over a week on it already. Please help!

Well. What I have done so far is the first bit of it (with the product of marginals)

```
ProductDistribution[
   BetaDistribution[1,2],BetaDistribution[2,2],BetaDistribution[3,1]
]
```

**Edit: **
The formula I want to create is number `8` in this paper
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4312/coleman.nb?file_id=3546

Here is my attempt so far:

```
    densities = ProductDistribution[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[1]], \[Beta]Vector[[1]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[2]], \[Beta]Vector[[2]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[3]], \[Beta]Vector[[3]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[4]], \[Beta]Vector[[4]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[5]], \[Beta]Vector[[5]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[6]], \[Beta]Vector[[6]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[7]], \[Beta]Vector[[7]]], BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[8]], \[Beta]Vector[[8]]]];
y = {Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[1]], \[Beta]Vector[[1]]], a]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[2]], \[Beta]Vector[[2]]], b]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1],CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[3]], \[Beta]Vector[[3]]], 
     c]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[4]], \[Beta]Vector[[4]]], 
     d]], 
   Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[5]], \[Beta]Vector[[5]]], 
     e]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[6]], \[Beta]Vector[[6]]], 
     f]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[7]], \[Beta]Vector[[7]]], 
     g]], Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    CDF[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha]Vector[[8]], \[Beta]Vector[[8]]], 
     h]]};
copula = Exp[(-y.(Inverse[exampleCorr] - 
          IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[exampleCorr][[1]]]).y)/2.]/
   Sqrt[Det[exampleCorr]];
```

The plan for me is to generate a random vector from that distribution.

Comment: Maybe you should try to create your own distribution in 1-D first... show what you have done, and how you want to generalize it to 3-D....

Comment: i have been able to do the first little bit. However, I now need to take the inverse standard normal of the cumulative distribution of one of the variables. I have no idea as to how to do this and be able to combine this with the product distribution

Comment: Have you loooked here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseGaussianDistribution.html

Comment: I tried something like PDF[InverseGaussianDistribution[0, 1],CDF[BetaDistribution[1,2],x]. However, there is an error and I have deduced it due to being the fact that I have a mean of 0.

Comment: Did you try to follow the examples on the help page? (The reason I ask is because the syntax does not look right in your comment above). The InverseGaussian cannot have a mean of zero, as stated clearly in the "Details" section.

Comment: Yea I did. I am not sure how to create the inverse standard normal because of this. If I use quantile as I have in my original statement, I am not sure how to use that in a probability distribution

Comment: Perhaps [this workshop](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8040/) may be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have already looked at that workshop before I submitted this question. Any other help would be greatly appreciated